# Data dependency between Grids, Stores

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am an ExtJs beginner and am working on an application made up of tabs, which all contain a grid (like an Excel document). The data comes from a node.js server.

There are two grids whose data depends on another grid's data (or even more, but for the example only one). The data which gets entered in grid1 will change the data of grid2 (if a new line is entered in grid1, then a corresponding line (different model) will appear in grid2). And if we change values in the new line in grid 2, then that will change some column values in the corresponding line in grid 1.

What is the correct way to approach this? 
Any time something is changed which affects the other grid, it should automatically have its affect (not only on lets say a save button pressed).

I have a couple of ideas, but with hardly any experience i have no idea if its the best way to do it (for example if a grids store is changed, then manually update the other effected stores in the controller threw the dataChanged event).

Comment: Maybe it will be more efficiently, if you update your grid data on tab change and save your changes as soon as something was changed. That will minimize the number of requests to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
The data itself doesn't need to be pushed back to the server on every value change, its enough on a save action called by the user. The only thing that is needed that the user can see the effect of his changes instantly on every tab. And at the end when he is satisfied with the result it can be saved to the server. But the question still stands, what is the best way to do this? Where to do it, how to do it.